# CMN_1949 Error:[Pre/Post Session Command] in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am getting the **error**:

CMN_1949 Error:[Pre/Post Session Command].The shell command failed with exit code=2.

The shell command contains only the code:

`/bin/rm $INFA_HOME/server/infa_shared/Cache/*.idx*;`

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using the shell command in windows environment and since it could not execute your command . Try using MS-DOS command if in case you are using in the windows enviromnent .  Use the command **del** inorder to delete the files . If you are using Unix environment kindly execute you command in the console and try , if you are getting any error .